# The Thread is On WaitSleepJoin State and is NOT Running anymore

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a multi-threaded application created on top of `C#`.

In my application i have 1 form with two panels.

- `pnlSearch`
- `pnlSlide`

Each one is controlled by each Thread:

- `TH_Slide`
- `TH_Search`

`TH_Slide` is called on the `Form_OnLoad` where i can display all information of  my objects inside the `pnlSlide`.

```
while(true)
{
    // do some infinite work to slide objects information.
    Thread.Sleep(20000); // display for 20 secs.
}
```

The `pnlSearch` is hidden and will show up when `TH_Search` is called this is handled when the mouse moved inside the form. And inside the `pnlSearch` there is `txtFilter` textBox and a `UserControl` object as a holder to display the searched information dynamically.

Now the problem is when i type in the `txtFilter` of a `pnlSearch` and load the information from my database and display it to the `UserControl`.

**The `TH_Slide.ThreadState` becomes `WaitSleepJoin` and would not running anymore hence the slide information in `pnlSlide` wont make any changes**.

> **NOTE:**  Cross Thread Operation is handled using delegates therefore it would not throw any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My application is now perfectly working by setting the

- `TH_Slide.IsBackground = true`
- `TH_Slide.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest`
- `TH_Search.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal`

I am new to multi-threading programming and i can't fully understand why this algorithm solves my problem.